# Scala Functional tests: How to do negative assertion?

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest, functional-testing

I have some restful services using Scala and play framework (2.4.*) and I am trying to write some functional tests for those services and getting hard time on negative assertions. For example :

**If I receive a response ( in Json) from my service like :**

```
{ "id":71324, "name":"Matt", "address":"24 Main st" }
```

**I am trying to check that :**

- "address" field exists and is non empty
- There **does not exist any key** named as "phone"

Finding hard time to find  an example on how to do the above to assertion.

**For other assertions, I did it this way:**

```
class IntegrationTest extends PlaySpec with OneServerPerSuite with MockitoSugar { // need with mockito*?

  override lazy val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
    .configure(Configuration.apply(ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("test/resources/testApplication.conf")).resolve()))
    .overrides(bind[EmployeeDAO].to[MockEmployeeDAO])
    .build
  implicit lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass)

  val wsClient = app.injector.instanceOf[WSClient]
  val myPublicAddress =  s"localhost:$port"


  "test1" must {
    "get employee record" in {
      val route = s"http://$myPublicAddress/INTERNAL/employee/7"
      val response = await(wsClient.url(route).get())
      log.debug(response.header("Content-Type") + " -> " + response.body)
      val jsonResponse = Json.parse(response.body)

      response.status mustBe OK

      (jsonResponse \ "id").get mustBe JsNumber(71324)
      (jsonResponse \ "name").get mustBe JsString("Matt")

      //trying to check that there is no phone

      //trying to check address fiels exists and is non-empty
      //(jsonResponse \ "address").get mustNot empty -- got systax error


    }

  }
}
```

May I get help here?

Comment: There is "mustNot". However, as I tried to use that, got meaningless error (compilation)

Comment: See "Being negative" in http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/matchers/must/Matchers.html

Comment: @Patty whenever asking programming questions, you should never summarize or paraphrase an error message. Always quote the error message in full, otherwise you risk omitting vital clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems with

```
(jsonResponse \ "address").get mustNot empty
```

The type of `(jsonResponse \ "address")` is `JsLookupResult` which has `isEmpty()` method, hence by [checking for emptiness](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingForEmptiness) it seems reasonable to try

```
(jsonResponse \ "address") mustNot be (empty)
```

However this does not work because [`empty`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.1.1/org/scalatest/enablers/Emptiness$.html) keyword DSL works on following types

- `scala.collection.GenTraversable`
- `String`
- `Array`
- `scala.Option`
- `java.util.Collection`
- `java.util.Map`
- arbitary object with a `isEmpty()` method that returns `Boolean`
- arbitary object with a `parameterless` isEmpty method that returns `Boolean`

where by "*arbitary object*" they really mean arbitrary [reference](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/4e1e38e2372ddada9037d442aa7efed1418119d9/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/enablers/Emptiness.scala#L148) object `AnyRef`

```
implicit def emptinessOfAnyRefWithIsEmptyMethod[T <: AnyRef { def isEmpty(): Boolean}]: Emptiness[T]
```

and `JsLookupResult` is [not](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/a77b03181b9ef86b48d0497272fa62a67860540d/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsLookup.scala#L134) a subtype of `AnyRef`

```
sealed trait JsLookupResult extends Any with JsReadable
```

Therefore, because constraint `T <: AnyRef { def isEmpty(): Boolean}` is not satisfied, we cannot use the nice emptiness DSL.

Alternatively the following should work

```
(jsonResponse \ "address").isEmpty mustBe false
(jsonResponse \ "address").isDefined mustBe true
```